# How do I fix this exception being thrown at a certain part of my code?

Tags: c++

When I build the code, I don't get any errors in the output window. However, after running it, the compiler throws an exception (I'll comment where it is being thrown) at my code saying "Exception thrown: read access violation.
temp was 0xCDCDCDCD.".

I tried researching what this error is, and I found that this is for unassigned memory, but I don't see where something is being unassigned.

This is my Linked List .cpp file. The exception is thrown at a line towards the end of this file.

```
#include "linkedlist.h"

struct ll::node 
{
    weapons data;
    node* next;
};

ll::ll()
{
    head = NULL;
}

ll::~ll()
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        node* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void ll::addItem(weapons obj)
{
    node* newNode = new node;
    node* temp = head;

    newNode->data = obj;

    if (head == NULL)
        head = newNode;
    return;

    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if (temp->next == NULL)
    {
        temp->next = newNode;
        return;
    }   
}

void ll::displayItems()
{
    for (node* temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
    {
            temp->data.getDescription(); //EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
    }
}
```

This file has the inherited class "Weapons" which is the object that is being called as "temp->data". As well as where I have "getDescription".

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//base class
class inventory
{
protected:
    //number of items in inventory
    int mNumItems;
public:
    //getters
    void displayInv();
    int getNumItems();
    virtual void getDescription();
};

//weapon class
class weapons : public inventory
{
private:
    //name of object
    string mName;
    //what the object is
    string mInfo;
    //how much of the object
    int mAmount;
    //how much damage does it do
    double mDamage;

public:
    //constructor
    weapons();
    weapons(string, string, double, int);
    //getters
    string getName();
    void getDescription();
    int getAmount();
    double getDamage();
    string getInfo();

    //mutators
    void setAmount(int);
};
```

This is where I define weapons

```
//weapon class
weapons::weapons()
{
    mName = " ";
    mInfo = " ";
    mDamage = 0.0;
    mAmount = 0;
}

weapons::weapons(string name, string info, double dmg, int amt)
{
    mName = name;
    mInfo = info;
    mDamage = dmg;
    mAmount = amt;
}

string weapons::getName()
{
    return mName;
}

int weapons::getAmount()
{
    return mAmount;
}

double weapons::getDamage()
{
    return mDamage;
}

string weapons::getInfo()
{
    return mInfo;
}

void weapons::getDescription()
{
    cout << getName() << ", " << getDamage() << " damage, " << getInfo() << " Amount: " << getAmount() << endl;
}

void weapons::setAmount(int amt)
{
    mAmount = amt;
}
```

Let me know if I need to include anymore files!

I get the expected results, which is for it to describe an item which I have in the Linked List. Unfortunately, my only problem is that this exception is being thrown.

Comment: Looks like you've been sloppy in making sure the `node` `next` pointers are being set correctly. I recommend giving `node` a constructor that automatically sets the value for you so that you cannot forget. That or chuck your linked list in favour of a library container like `std::list`.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you! Unfortunately, I've got to use a linked list per my requirements.

Comment: I went into my function and I cleaned it up a bit and looked at some old code and that fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: I agree that you shouldn’t implement things that are refill available in the standard library. Of course this may be an assignment where the standard library containers are not an option.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano If there's nothing in the question that says they have to make their own list, string, vector, or what-have-you, I always make the suggestion because the asker may be putting themselves through this hell for no good reason.

Comment: @user4581301 I didn’t mean to call you out. There wasn’t any mention of requirements when I wrote that.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano No worries. No bruised ego here. Just explaining my logic.

Comment: [CRT Debug Heap Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details): *"New objects are filled with 0xCD when they are allocated."* When you see a fill pattern of `0xCD` in your code then that usually amounts to an uninitialized object. To verify, write `int i;`, and observe the value of `i` in your debugger.

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

In

```
struct ll::node 
{
    weapons data;
    node* next;
};
```

and

```
void ll::addItem(weapons obj)
{
    node* newNode = new node; // leaks if node not added
    node* temp = head;

    newNode->data = obj;

    if (head == NULL)
        head = newNode;
    return; // this is a NASTY bug of a different sort. Most of the time 
            // the function will exit without doing ANYTHING

    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if (temp->next == NULL) // the only way out of the above loop is if 
                            // temp->next == NULL. This if is redundant.
    {
        temp->next = newNode;
        return;
    }   
}
```

Nothing ever sets `newNode->next` to a safe value. That allows

```
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
```

to fail because there are no guarantees that `temp->next` is ever `NULL` and the loop goes marching off the end of the list.

## Solution

Force `next` to a safe value.

```
struct ll::node 
{
    weapons data;
    node* next = NULL;
};
```

Or a more versatile version

```
struct ll::node 
{
    weapons data;
    node* next;
    node(const weapons & weap, // const reference eliminates a possible copy
         node * link = NULL): // if you know what the next link will be, 
                              // you can add it here. If not, it's always NULL
        data(weap),
        next(link) 
    {
    }    
};
```

`addItem` now looks something like

```
void ll::addItem(const weapons & obj) 
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = new node(obj); // only making node if we need it
                              // less chance of leak
    }
    else
    {
        node * temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode(obj);
    }
}
```

But you can do something really sneaky here to make life easier. `head` is really a `next` pointer by another name, so if you can abstract the different name... And we can by tracking a pointer to `next` rather than a pointer to the `node`. This is really handy when you have to insert or remove an item: You have a reference both to the node in question and the insertion point in the previous node.

```
void ll::addItem(const weapons & obj) 
{
    node ** temp = &head; // get pointer to insertion point
    while ((*temp) != NULL) // next node, including head, is not null
    {
        temp = &(*temp)->next; // get pointer to next insertion point
    }
    *temp = newNode(obj); // insert node
}
```

Half the code. Example of how this helps remove:

```
void ll::removeItem(const weapons & obj) 
{
    node ** temp = &head; 
    while ((*temp) != NULL && (*temp)->data != obj) 
    {
        temp = &(*temp)->next; 
    }
    if  (*temp != NULL) // found it!
    {
        node * rem = *temp; // get node to remove so we don't lose it when we relink
        *temp = rem->next; // point at item after rem
        delete rem; // release item
    }
}
```

Comment: Note [the rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three): *"If a class requires a **user-defined destructor**, a user-defined copy constructor, or a user-defined copy assignment operator, it almost certainly requires all three."*